# Google has logged in from Firebase Authentication but I can't find the user gender in the flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-dependencies, flutter-web, flutter-animation

**I was try to get gender data but google sign always loading. I’m waiting more than 15 minutes 4 times. but I'm not received data and stop my run project.**

I can't find a way to get it. I used some method but it doesn't work.

**So, Please help me to get successfully gender value in Firebase Auth - Google SingIn.**

```
import 'package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart';
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:google_sign_in/google_sign_in.dart';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;
import 'dart:convert';

class SignInView extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _SignInViewState createState() => _SignInViewState();
}

class _SignInViewState extends State<SignInView> {
  FirebaseAuth _auth = FirebaseAuth.instance;

  GoogleSignIn _googleSignIn = new GoogleSignIn(scopes: [
    'email',
    'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/user.gender.read',
    'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.profile',
  ]);

  _getGender() async {
    final headers = await _googleSignIn.currentUser.authHeaders;
    final r = await http.get(
        "https://people.googleapis.com/v1/people/me?personFields=genders&key=AIzaSyD8ftzpg0m2GlpOlnCx22IsGsPn35_GXAQ",
        headers: {"Authorization": headers["Authorization"]});
    final response = jsonDecode(r.body);
    print(response["genders"][0]["formattedValue"]);
  }

  _handleSignIn() async {
    GoogleSignInAccount googleSignInAccount = await _googleSignIn.signIn();
    GoogleSignInAuthentication googleSignInAuthentication =
        await googleSignInAccount.authentication;

    AuthCredential credential = GoogleAuthProvider.credential(
        idToken: googleSignInAuthentication.idToken,
        accessToken: googleSignInAuthentication.accessToken);

    UserCredential result = (await _auth.signInWithCredential(credential));

    _getGender();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      home: Scaffold(
          appBar: AppBar(
            title: Text("Sign In"),
            backgroundColor: Colors.black87,
            leading: IconButton(
                icon: Icon(Icons.arrow_back_ios_sharp, color: Colors.white),
                onPressed: () {
                  Navigator.of(context).pop();
                }),
          ),
          body: Center(
            child: Container(
              padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 5, right: 15, bottom: 5),
              child: FlatButton(
                onPressed: () {
                  _handleSignIn();
                },
                shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20.0),
                    side: BorderSide(color: Colors.red)),
                color: Colors.black87,
                textColor: Colors.white,
                padding:
                    EdgeInsets.only(left: 30, top: 10, right: 30, bottom: 10),
                splashColor: Colors.black87,
                child: Text(
                  "SIGN IN",
                  style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20),
                ),
              ),
            ),
          )),
    );
  }
}
```

[image]

Comment: please check, shared my code

Answer (score 0):

**First Issue**

Google sigin with flutter does not allow you to get user's gender.

**Second Issue**

In order to make Google Sign-in work on a real device, you need to add **Sha1** , **Sha5** certificate fingerprint from **Google Play console** *App signing** section to firebase console.

> Firebase Console > Android App > Settings > Sha Keys

Google Signing should work after this.

P.S: Alss try if Google signing works with only one of the Sha keys or both are needed(I added both to be on the safe side).

Comment: **https://www.googleapis.com/auth/user.gender.read**


If I remove this line from google scope then google signin works. But if you add it to scope, google signin will stop working.

Comment: So adding sha keys made didn't make any difference?
Just curious

Not sure about google api for gender!

Comment: In my app I'm providing user an option to edit their profile, and managing user gender there. Not sure about google api for gender.

Comment: okay bro, thanks for try to find out! you idea is good.

Comment: If my answer was helpful, I would appreciate if you mark it correct to help other users with similar question :)

Comment: sure bro, I'll try to help another people with you technicse